# Database normalization: Which is the best fit?

Tags: mysql, database-design, normalization

I have 3 different types of data set:

#### Notification:

- start_date
- end_date
- notification_type
- country_id
- state_id

#### Campaign:

- start_date
- end_date
- user_notification

#### Transaction

- email
- transaction_value

All these 3 have the same types of child tables where there will be foreign keys pointing to these tables.

What type of design will be best?

1. 3 different tables and one child table that will have 3 different columns as primary keys pointing to each different parent?
2. 1 combined parent table allowing null values for columns which will be not needed for any particular type and a `main_type` column which says whether each record is a *campaign*, a *notification* or a *transaction*. The child table will have only one foreign key column.
3. 3 different tables, 1 for each of the main table types with a child table for each main table that uses the main table's primary key as a foreign key.

Comment: What's the proposed schema for the unified child table?

Comment: child tables are also like this... like they are also having so many null columns in table depending on what type of data it is... !! like if ther is campaign there will be 4-5 null columns...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Having the same types of columns is not the same thing as being the same *entity type*.  **Normalization is not the same thing as code reuse**.

Normalization is about arranging your columns into tables in such a way that you avoid insert, update and delete anomalies.  It is about reducing the kinds of redundancy that can lead to these anomalies, it isn't about putting things together because they look alike.

As a first choice, you should let your database engine use its declarative constraints (foreign keys, unique keys, etc.) to protect the integrity of your data.  This saves writing application code to do this and makes your system less buggy in the long run.

**This means that you should aim for at least third normal form (3NF) by default and then consider later whether any denormalization is necessary.**

From this perspective, your first option is not good, because you are jamming three different kinds of child data into one table.  You can't control referential integrity as cleanly or easily this way.  The only two conventional, practical options you have are 2 and 3.

Choosing between options 2 and 3 depends on the circumstances, and may depend quite a bit on your personal preferences.  Some people would avoid option 2 because they believe all nulls are evil.  Other people would avoid option 3 because they don't like having too many different tables.  This is a "holy war" debate without a definitive, logical answer.

For practical purposes, looking at your three main tables, I would say that they don't look like they have very much in common.  There is a little overlap, but not very much.  **Therefore, I would tend towards option 3.**  Keep your tables separate so that your code and your data stay clean.

As an aside: You don't show the details of the child table(s).  If these three child tables have an identical structure and you're worried about having application code that is duplicated, consider creating a class that handles the child table structure and inheriting from this class for each of the three child tables.  This will give you code reuse without compromising data integrity.

Comment: For huge tables, Normalization can also be about saving space.  You have hinted at such with `country_id`.

Answer (score 1):

Having seperate entities for seperate concepts will be easy to analyse and manage in future when the system size increases. Also we never knows what will be the new concepts our system needs in future, it may change, in this case seperate tables are good option. May be following model will work for you.

```
Country { Country Name}

State {Country Name, State Name}

Year {Year}

Month {Year, Month}

Date { Month, Date}

Email {Email Address}

Type {Notification Type}

Notification {Type, Date, State}

Campaign {Notification, Date}

Transaction {Email, Value}
```

At the begining it seems very large number of tables and may consume huge amount of time, but in the long run our requirements may change in future at that time, this kind model will be helpful for us.

Also, seperate tables allow us to easly add new instances to our master table fields, in real world it is necessary to have such provision.

Comment: This is what I call "over-normalization".  You will be in trouble when trying to do a date range.